# Move Javascript const from block scope to global

Tags: javascript, scope, constants, block

I have a file I am including in my html files containing constants for my Javascript code. I also want to ensure that the constants are not redefined - a syntax error occurs if you try. If it was PHP I would use requires_once to prevent multiple inclusions. You can check if a constant is defined with an if test but the problem is that if you define the const in the if block it is block scoped and not global. For example

```
if (typeof A === 'undefined') {
    const A = "A String";
    const B = "B String";
    const C = "C String";
    const D = "D String";
}
```

The constants A, B, C and D are only defined within the if block. I want to promote them to the global scope. As they are constants they can't be changed so the usual problem with global variables is avoided.

Comment: Move the code which uses them inside the if block?

Comment: *"I also want to ensure that the constants are not redefined"* - It sounds like this is **really** an issue of how the code is organized and delivered to the client, not an issue of scope.  If you're including the same code multiple times and trying to define the same constants multiple times, **that** is the problem to correct.  Rather than try to hide/circumvent the problem by messing with scope.  Solving **that** problem may involve not using global scope in the first place, may involve using modules, may involve tools like WebPack, etc.

Comment: That's not possible with JS. Define the `consts` on a global scope and make sure, the file containing them is included only once ... (And be aware, that polluting the global scope with such consts is discouraged, but that's a different topic)

Comment: You _could_ do `Object.defineProperty(window, 'A', { value: 'A String', writable: false, configurable: false })` (this will work when run multiple times with the same value but throw an exception if attempted with a different one) but I feel like this is an XY problem and you are already too far down the wrong path anyway. You should consider ES Modules.

Comment: Yes, modules is most def the way to go, even before ES6 modules, with commonJS/AMD etc, you would do it using modules, you don't even require the `once`, as modules are singletons anyway.

Answer (score 4):

For global variables that may (accidentally) get declared multiple times, use `var`. And just overwrite the previous value by assignment, given it's constant, it would have had the same value before (or you're in trouble anyway).

A much better solution though is not to use global variables but ES6 modules. Declare the `const` in your module's scope, `export` it, and then `import` the module where you need it. Multiple imports will always return the same module, so it does not get re-evaluated.

If switching to modules in not possible, you may continue using global `const` declarations, but what you really need to do is to avoid including your script multiple times into the same page, as suggested by @David in the comments.

Comment: "*And just overwrite the previous value by assignment, given it's constant,*" but that does not prevent some accidental `A = "something wrong"` somewhere in the code as a `const A = ...` would do ...  But I agree, using modules is the preferred way ...

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. The code is a legacy application, written before ES6, so I didn't want to make too many changes in case something is broken. Changing the const to var looks like the quickest solution although that isn't the best solution.